# JS clock doesn't work when in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

My issue is that the JS clock seems to work fine when it's placed directly in the head of my HTML document, but fails to work when I load it from an external .js file. Many other things in my .js file work, just not this one! Any idea what the issue could be?

```
    function startTime() {
    var today=new Date(),
        h=today.getHours(),
        m=today.getMinutes(),
        s=today.getSeconds();

    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('bigtime').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {
        i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyydz).

Edit: I'm loading my js file like this in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

right after my jquery file.

and like this in my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

});
```

Comment: How are you loading your javascript file?

Comment: I edited my original post. thanks for the response!

Comment: I'm putting it in the head of my html doc

Comment: See, in jsFiddle you chose the `onLoad` option. So if you remove the inline onload from the body and just put `startTime();` at the bottom of the JavaScript, it works. Here's the [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyydz/3/) to recreate your situation. (You can also move the functions above `$(function() { ... })`)

Comment: Hey nvm that worked! Thank you :-) If you want to submit this as an answer I'll accept it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your jsFiddle you chose the `onLoad` option.
If you remove the inline onload from the body and just put `startTime();` at the bottom of the JavaScript, it works.
 But that's only like that on jsFiddle. In "real world" situations you need to place your script either in the body or in the head with an event listener on page load.

The jQuery abbreviation for this is `$(function() { /* executed after page load */ });`

As you mentioned, you're using jQuery, [here's a solution with the jQuery onload](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyydz/4/):

```
function startTime()
{
  /* ... */
}
// after the whole page is loaded, execute the previously declared startTime()
$(function() {
  startTime();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would load in jquery library and do a in the JS-file 
http://jsfiddle.net/X5njR/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
startTime();  
});
```

this makes the HTML Cleaner and keeps all JS in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually have it already in the $(document).ready function in my js file but it just makes it a static clock with no movement until I refresh :-(

Comment: It works in the fiddle, are you sure you are using it the same way? (No onload attribute in the body?)

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle's `onLoad` option wraps your whole JS in `//<![CDATA[ window.onload=function(){` and `}//]]>`

This means your `startTime` function is not defined until after your `onload` event handler on `body` fires.

Use the `No wrap - in <head>` option to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I made a clock with TypeScript.

Here I pass the functionality of the clock.

```
/**
 * @class
 * @name Time
 */
class Time
{
    private millisecond: number;
    private second: number;
    private minute: number;
    private hour: number;
    private day: number;
    private year: number;



    /**
     * @hideconstructor
     * @param {number} millisecond
     * @param {number} second
     * @param {number} minute
     * @param {number} hour
     * @param {number} day
     * @param {number} year
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public constructor(millisecond: number = NaN,
                       second: number = NaN,
                       minute: number = NaN,
                       hour: number = NaN,
                       day: number = NaN,
                       year: number = NaN)
    {
        this.millisecond = millisecond;
        this.second = second;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }



    //Getters and Setters.
    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.getMillisecond
     * @returns {number}
     */
    public getMillisecond(): number
    {
        return this.millisecond;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.setMillisecond
     * @param {number} millisecond
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public setMillisecond(millisecond: number): void
    {
        this.millisecond = millisecond;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.getSecond
     * @returns {number}
     */
    public getSecond(): number
    {
        return this.second;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.setSecond
     * @param {number} second
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public setSecond(second: number): void
    {
        this.second = second;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.getMinute
     * @returns {number}
     */
    public getMinute(): number
    {
        return this.minute;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.setMinute
     * @param {number} minute
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public setMinute(minute: number): void
    {
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.getHour
     * @returns {number}
     */
    public getHour(): number
    {
        return this.hour;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.setHour
     * @param {number} hour
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public setHour(hour: number): void
    {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.getDay
     * @returns {number}
     */
    public getDay(): number
    {
        return this.day;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.setDay
     * @param {number} day
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public setDay(day: number): void
    {
        this.day = day;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.getYear
     * @returns {number}
     */
    public getYear(): number
    {
        return this.year;
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.setYear
     * @param {number} year
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public setYear(year: number): void
    {
        this.year = year;
    }



    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.today
     * @returns {Date}
     */
    public today(): Date
    {
        return new Date();
    }



    //Time format.
    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.year_format
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public year_format(): string
    {
        this.setYear(this.today().getFullYear())

        if (this.getYear().valueOf() >= 0 &&
            this.getYear().valueOf() < 10)
        {
            return `000${this.getYear()}`;
        }
        else
        if (this.getYear().valueOf() >= 10 &&
            this.getYear().valueOf() < 100)
        {
            return `00${this.getYear()}`;
        }
        else
        if (this.getYear().valueOf() >= 100 &&
            this.getYear().valueOf() < 1000)
        {
            return `0${this.getYear()}`;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getYear().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.day_format
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public day_format(): string
    {
        this.setDay(this.today().getDate());

        if (this.getDay().valueOf() >= 0 &&
            this.getDay().valueOf() < 10)
        {
            return `0${this.getDay()}`;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getDay().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.hour_format
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public hour_format(): string
    {
        this.setHour(this.today().getHours());

        if (this.getHour().valueOf() >= 0 &&
            this.getHour().valueOf() < 10)
        {
            return `0${this.getHour()}`;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getHour().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.minutes_format
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public minutes_format(): string
    {
        this.setMinute(this.today().getMinutes());

        if (this.getMinute().valueOf() >= 0 &&
            this.getMinute().valueOf() < 10)
        {
            return `0${this.getMinute()}`;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getMinute().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.second_format
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public second_format(): string
    {
        this.setSecond(this.today().getSeconds());

        if (this.getSecond().valueOf() >= 0 &&
            this.getSecond().valueOf() < 10)
        {
            return `0${this.getSecond()}`;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getSecond().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.millisecond_format
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public millisecond_format(): string
    {
        this.setMillisecond(this.today().getMilliseconds());

        if (this.getMillisecond().valueOf() >= 0 &&
            this.getMillisecond().valueOf() < 10)
        {
            return `000${this.getMillisecond()}`;
        }
        else
        if (this.getMillisecond().valueOf() >= 10 &&
            this.getMillisecond().valueOf() < 100)
        {
            return `00${this.getMillisecond()}`;
        }
        else
        if (this.getMillisecond().valueOf() >= 100 &&
            this.getMillisecond().valueOf() < 1000)
        {
            return `0${this.getMillisecond()}`;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getMillisecond().toString();
        }
    }



    //Current.
    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.current_month
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public current_month(): string
    {
        //Constants.
        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {Array<string>}
         * @alias months
         */
        const months: Array<string> = [
            `January`,
            `February`,
            `March`,
            `April`,
            `May`,
            `June`,
            `July`,
            `August`,
            `September`,
            `October`,
            `November`,
            `December`
        ];

        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {number}
         * @alias month
         */
        const month: number = this.today().getMonth();

        return months[month];
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Time.current_day
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public current_day(): string
    {
        //Constants.
        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {Array<string>}
         * @alias week
         */
        const week: Array<string> = [
            `Sunday`,
            `Monday`,
            `Tuesday`,
            `Wednesday`,
            `Thursday`,
            `Friday`,
            `Saturday`
        ];

        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {number}
         * @alias weekday
         */
        const weekday: number = this.today().getDay();

        return week[weekday];
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @class
 * @name Clock
 */
class Clock extends Time
{
    /**
     * @hideconstructor
     * @param {number} millisecond
     * @param {number} second
     * @param {number} minute
     * @param {number} hour
     * @param {number} day
     * @param {number} year
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public constructor(millisecond: number = NaN,
                       second: number = NaN,
                       minute: number = NaN,
                       hour: number = NaN,
                       day: number = NaN,
                       year: number = NaN)
    {
        super
        (
            millisecond,
            second,
            minute,
            hour,
            day,
            year
        );
    }



    /**
     * @access private
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.span_day
     * @param {string} id
     * @returns {HTMLSpanElement}
     */
    private span_day(id: string): HTMLSpanElement
    {
        return (window.document.getElementById(id) as HTMLSpanElement);
    }

    /**
     * @access private
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.span_time
     * @param {string} id
     * @returns {HTMLSpanElement}
     */
    private span_time(id: string): HTMLSpanElement
    {
        return (window.document.getElementById(id) as HTMLSpanElement);
    }



    /**
     * @access private
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.time
     * @returns {string}
     */
    private time(): string
    {
        //Objects.
        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {object}
         * @alias time
         */
        const time: Time = new Time();

        return `${time.hour_format()}:${time.minutes_format()}:${time.second_format()}:${time.millisecond_format()}`;
    }

    /**
     * @access private
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.short_date
     * @returns {string}
     */
    private short_date(): string
    {
        //Objects.
        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {object}
         * @alias time
         */
        const time: Time = new Time();

        return time.today().toLocaleDateString();
    }

    /**
     * @access private
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.long_date
     * @returns {string}
     */
    private long_date(): string
    {
        //Objects.
        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {object}
         * @alias time
         */
        const time: Time = new Time();

        return `${time.current_day()}, ${time.current_month()} ${time.day_format()}, ${time.year_format()}`;
    }



    //Clock.
    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.clock__short
     * @param {string} day_id
     * @param {string} time_id
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public clock__short(day_id: string,
                        time_id: string): void
    {
        window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            /**
             * @access private
             * @constant
             * @type {object}
             * @alias clock
             */
            const clock: Clock = new Clock();

            clock.span_day(day_id).innerHTML = clock.short_date();
        }, 0);

        window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            /**
             * @access private
             * @constant
             * @type {object}
             * @alias clock
             */
            const clock: Clock = new Clock();

            clock.span_time(time_id).innerHTML = clock.time();
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * @access public
     * @method
     * @alias Clock.clock__long
     * @param {string} day_id
     * @param {string} time_id
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public clock__long(day_id: string,
                       time_id: string): void
    {
        window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            /**
             * @access private
             * @constant
             * @type {object}
             * @alias clock
             */
            const clock: Clock = new Clock();

            clock.span_day(day_id).innerHTML = clock.long_date();
        }, 0);

        window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            /**
             * @access private
             * @constant
             * @type {object}
             * @alias Clock.clock__long.clock
             */
            const clock: Clock = new Clock();

            clock.span_time(time_id).innerHTML = clock.time();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @function
 * @name clock
 * @param {string} day_id This ID refers to the ID of the HTML where you want to put the day.
 * @param {string} time_id This ID refers to the ID of the HTML where you want to put the time.
 * @param {string} type The "type" refers to whether the clock is Long or Short.
 * @returns {void}
 * @summary This function is to insert a clock on the page.
 */
function clock(day_id: string,
               time_id: string,
               type: string): void
{
    try
    {
        //Objects.
        /**
         * @access private
         * @constant
         * @type {object}
         * @alias clock
         */
        const clock: Clock = new Clock();



        if (type === `Long`)
        {
            clock.clock__long(day_id, time_id);
        }
        else
        if (type === `Short`)
        {
            clock.clock__short(day_id, time_id);
        }
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
        window.console.error(`Unexpected error. | Error name: ${(exception as Error).name}; Error message: ${(exception as Error).message}`);
    }
}
```

---

At least for me, this code (already made JavaScript and put from the Head) works for me. I get it to work by calling the function from the script tag that is at the end of the body tag.